# 'yahoo' does not match format

Tags: python, finance

I am trying to fetch the S&P500 data from yahoo.
Installed the fix_yahoo_finance already, and using yf.download()

I try to runt the code and it gives me the following output

ValueError: time data 'yahoo' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'

The code looks as such:

```
import bs4 as bs
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime
import os 
import pandas as pd
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import fix_yahoo_finance
import pickle 
import requests
def save_sp500_tickers():
    resp = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find('table', {'class':'wikitable sortable'})
    tickers = []
    for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
        ticker = row.findAll('td')[0].text
        tickers.append(ticker)

    with open('sp500tickers.pickle','wb') as f:
              pickle.dump(tickers, f)
    print(tickers)  

    return tickers


#save_sp500_tickers()


def get_data_from_yahoo(reload_sp500=False):
    if reload_sp500:
        tickers = save_sp500_tickers()
    else:
        with open('sp500tickers.pickle','rb') as f:
            tickers = pickle.load(f)

    if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs'):
        os.makedirs('stock_dfs')



    for ticker in tickers:
        print(ticker)
        if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker)):
           start = dt.datetime(2000,1,1)
           end = dt.datetime(2016,12,31)
            df = yf.download(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
            df.to_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
        else:
            print('Already have{}'.format(ticker))

get_data_from_yahoo()
```

I am a beginner (been exploring python for a month) so the solution might be easy but I could not find something that actually answered my question.

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like the request should be formatted date information, but instead you are passing 'yahoo'.

Comment: Just remove yahoo from `df = yf.download(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)` why do you have it? python is interpreting it as the start time for your download

Comment: to be honest, I am not sure. I am following a tutorial. 
however, my intention is to put all the tickers in a csv file

Comment: @sean666 
I deleted 'yahoo' from the code and now I am trying to run it, its working on it.. I will keep updating if it solved it.

Comment: seems like it solved it for now, now I have another error but nothing that has to do with the dates or anything.. Thank  you!

Comment: this solution might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62677124/how-to-use-google-as-a-data-source-for-pandas-data-reader/76369910#76369910